# Function called only in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with in Unity  and Visual Studio 2017 and I'm having a problem with a function being called only when debugger is attached.
I have two functions:

```
void foo()
{
//some code that does something
}

void bar()
{
//empty function
}
```

Bar is called when a button is clicked, since it's empty nothing happens.
But if I attach Unity Debugger (Attach to Unity), set breakpoint in bar and then click button again, bar gets called and then foo gets called.

Foo used to be called from bar but I've changed that, yet it's still called in debug.

I havent been able to find a reason for this behaviour, is this some kind of caching done by VS ? I tried restarting Unity, VS, even my pc but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: I think (not entirely sure) this has something to do with the compiler optimazation. If the function is really empty, it just get thrown away, so you cannot break on it.

Comment: If I add something to bar function, like Debug.log("Something"), the foo function still gets called only in debug.

Comment: Do you have in your `web.config` file a line like `<compilation optimizeCompilations="true">`?

Comment: I don't think I have such a file, I cant find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you dont have web.config file. And i think you just disable debug messege in Debug window.Check it and then comment.